# Is it necessary to use 2 canvas for the html5 video manipulation?

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas

I try to do some video manipulation in javascript. I read some article about it and looks like everybody uses 2 canvas to do the trick. First of all, they draw the video on the first canvas, they read the image data from it, do some pixel manipulation and after that they draw it on the second canvas. I was wondering that I really have to use 2 canvas to do this? Isn't there any method to grab the image data directly from the video? Or we have some performance issue and this is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you can't get the pixel data from video.

The Canvas API has a method `getImageData()` which gives back a floating point array with values for every colour (and alpha) for every pixel. Unfortunately, the video element can't do that :(

You can use **one** canvas which draws the video frame and manipulates it too. I guess people prefer doing it on two canvases so that they can keep the original pixel data in case you there's a change manipulation before a new frame is loaded or something...